# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_OBJECT'

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures

I'm getting all columns from a table and fetching the result to JSON using the function JSON_OBJECT. But when i execute the stored procedure i'm getting this error.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sistema`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_products_as_json`()
BEGIN

SET @fields = (
    'SELECT 
        group_concat(\'\`\', column_name, \'\`\, \', column_name)
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE
        table_schema = DATABASE()
            AND table_name = \'products\'
    ORDER BY table_name , ordinal_position'
);

SET @stmt = ('SELECT JSON_OBJECT(?) FROM products LIMIT 10');
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt USING @fields;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use prepared statements in that way.

You have to CONCAT the variable.

I also changed the first SELECT, this works too and is better to read.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`sistema`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_products_as_json`()
BEGIN

SET @fields = (
    SELECT 
        group_concat('"', column_name, '", ', column_name)  
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE
        table_schema = DATABASE()
            AND table_name = 'products'
    ORDER BY table_name , ordinal_position
);

SET @stmt =  CONCAT('SELECT json_object(',@fields,') FROM products LIMIT 10');
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I added also the DELIMITER in case you don_'t use mysql workbench